# How to use parameters is list in dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have check "is list" in parameters
but it does not work
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYyL6.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you also check the "is list" at at the intent page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).